# Can't send wchar_t array through mailslot

Tags: c, winapi, client-server, mailslot

I can't send chunks of data bigger than `420` bytes. For example if i try to send `421 bytes`, i can't read it with `ReadFile`. If I check the maislot info with `GetMailslotInfo( handleRead, 0, &msgSize, 0, 0 );` then `msgSize` will always be `-1`.

So this will never work for me:

```
err = WriteFile( handleWrite, wcharArrayToSend, 421, &numBytesWritten, NULL );
```

Does anyone know a reason for this behavior? Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: There is a client and a server I'm working with. Here is the client code: http://pastebin.com/iq76EvAN and here is the server code http://pastebin.com/fy5nCd1t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MSDN's documentation on mailslots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365130(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The data in a mailslot message can be in any form, but cannot be larger than 424 bytes when sent between computers.
>
> To send messages that are larger than 424 bytes between computers, use [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Windows Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: Note: that's specific to sending *between* computers. If your client and server are on the same computer, it doesn't seem to apply (but, given the OP's symptom, it's probably a fair guess that this is the source of his problem).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've done wrong, but mailslots can definitely handle messages greater than 421 bytes. Here's some test code (that runs successfully):

Server:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    HANDLE mailslot = CreateMailslot("\\\\.\\mailslot\\myslot", 
        0, 
        MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, 
        NULL);
    if (mailslot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create mailslot.");
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[2048];
    OVERLAPPED ovlp = {0};

    ovlp.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);   
    if (ovlp.hEvent == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create Event.");
        return 2;
    }

    DWORD read;

    do { 
        ReadFile(mailslot, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, &ovlp);
        buffer[read] = 0;
        WaitForSingleObject(ovlp.hEvent, INFINITE);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    } while (strcmp(buffer, "exit"));    
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    HANDLE mailslot = CreateFile("\\\\.\\mailslot\\myslot", 
        GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
        NULL, 
        OPEN_ALWAYS, 
        0, 
        NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == mailslot) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open mailslot.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buffer[2048];
    DWORD written;

    for (int i=0; i<1024; i++)
        buffer[i] = 'A' + (i%26);
    buffer[1023] = '\0';
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);

    WriteFile(mailslot, buffer, len, &written, NULL);    
    WriteFile(mailslot, "exit", 4, &written, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
E:\C\source>mailslot
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
STUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
YZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
exit
```

Comment: @AdamMaras: I've added the output to show it does work (though I'm certainly not going to claim that doing this is a great idea). FWIW, this was tested in Windows 7.

Comment: I removed my comment; after reading the documentation, I realized that the 424-byte limit applies to mailslots across computers (per my answer.)

Comment: @AdamMaras: Yup -- noted (and emphasized in my comment).